# Downloading file from the website - HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, edgar

I am trying to download 10Ks (annual report of public companies) from EDGAR. I am running the code below (used it from the textbook, don't understand much of it), but keep getting the following error: (I downloaded 'master.idx' files that are described in the code before running the code below).

> HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Can you please help me to resolve it?

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path

def get_files(start_year:int, end_year:int,
              reform:str, 
              inddirect:str, odirect:str):
"""
Downloads SEC filings for specific companies
start_year -> First Year to download
end_year -> Last Year to download
reform -> Regex to specify forms to be downloaded
inddirect -> Directory containing index files
odirect -> Directory the filings will be downloaded to
"""

    print('Downloading Filings')

# Regex to identify the form to download.
    re_formtype = re.compile(reform, re.IGNORECASE)
# Regex to extract file name information 
# from a line
    re_fullfilename = re.compile(r"\|(edgar/data.*\/([\d-]+\.txt))", re.IGNORECASE)

#loop through the index files based on year
    for year in range(start_year, end_year+1):
    #check whether the directory exists and create one 
    # if it does not.
        download_path = os.path.join(odirect, str(year))
        if not os.path.exists(download_path):
            os.makedirs(download_path)
            
        for qtr in range(1,5):
        #name of index file to be read.
            dl_file = os.path.join(inddirect, 'master' + str(year) + str(qtr) + '.idx')
    
        # check to see if the index file exists.
            if not os.access(dl_file, os.R_OK):
            # Download the index file if it does not 
            # already exist
                url='https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/' + str(year) + '/' + 'QTR' + str(qtr) + '/master.idx'
            # download the file defined as url and 
            # download to the file defined a dl_fle.
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dl_file)
        # open the index file
            with open(dl_file, 'r') as f:
            # set a counter called count to 1. Note 
            # that the counter will only be incremented 
            # after it downloads a file.
                count=1
            
            # loop through each line in the index file, 
            # assigning to a variable called line
                for line in f:
                # Only download a file if the counter 
                # is less than 5.
                # Remove this if statement if you want
                # to download all the files for the
                # time period
                    if count<5:
                    # Check to see if the the line  
                    # matches the form type 
                        rematch=re.search(re_formtype,line)
                    #If there is a match then download 
                    # the filing
                        if rematch:
                        # The following line searches 
                        # for filename information. 
                        # The first grouping will 
                        # contain the location and 
                        # filename of the file to be 
                        # downloaded. The second
                        # grouping will contain just 
                        # the filename o
                            matches = re.search(re_fullfilename, line)
                            if matches:
                            # Construct the url to for 
                            # retrieving the filing 
                                url = str('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/') + str(matches.group(1))
                            # Create the filename to 
                            # download the file to.
                                outfile = os.path.join(download_path, 
                                                   str(matches.group(2)))
                            # Check to make sure the  
                            # file hasn't already 
                            # been downloaded
                                                   
                                if not (os.path.isfile(outfile) and os.access(outfile, os.R_OK)):
                                # Print the name of the 
                                # file to be downloaded.
                                    print("Downloading:"+str(outfile),end='\n')
                                #downlaod the file
                                    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, outfile)    
                                    count += 1
    print('Downloading of Filings Complete',end='\n')
    return
                                                   
# Specify, in regular expression format, the filing
# you are looking for.  Following is the for 10-k.
reform='(\|10-?k(sb|sb40|405)?\s*\|)'

# Specify location of the index files.
inddirect = os.path.join(Path.home(), 'edgar', 'indexfiles')

# Specify where to download filings to
odirect = os.path.join(Path.home(), 'edgar', '10K')

# Execute the get filings function
get_files(2018, 2019, reform, inddirect, odirect)
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line:

```
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dl_file)
```

with these line, as you are missing the user-agent

```
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'MyApp/1.0')]
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dl_file)
```